# Answering prompt using vagrant file?

Tags: vagrant, docker, vagrantfile

Is it possible to add a script to a Vagrantfile that answers a prompt. I am provisioning a ubuntu box for docker

```
config.vm.box = "ubuntu"

config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get update"

config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-generic-lts-raring"
```

After running the last command, there is a prompt that asks

```
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

An easier solution would be to use the `-y` option of `apt-get`:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => "sudo apt-get -y install linux-image-generic-lts-raring linux-headers-generic-lts-raring"
```

See the [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get):

> -y, --yes, --assume-yes Automatic yes to prompts. Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable
>   situation, such as changing a held package or removing an essential
>   package, occurs then apt-get will abort.

Comment: What if the thing you're trying to do does not have a `-y` option or similar?

Comment: In that case you can use something like a tool called yes (on ubuntu it is /usr/bin/yes)

example:
    /usr/bin/yes | pip uninstall combox